# Analysis of Testing Report of Caliper

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

My Question is:

Q1. What do we mean by 'label 1, 2' and how 4 Peers are contributing to it?

Q2. What do we mean by label 3, when we compare it with 'send rate' ?

Q3. What is difference between label 3 and lable 5 and why there is much gap in memory utilization of both?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Lable 1 is the number of transactions that were successfully processed and written on the ledger. Lable 2 is the number of transactions that are being submitted every second. Lable 2 has nothing to do with the number of peers but the number of peers (and their processing power) contributes to this as if a peer fails to do its job (endorsement, verification, etc.) the transaction would fail therefore this number would be different.

Q2: Lable 3 represents the number of transaction that has been processed vs send rate which is the per second rate of the transactions submitted to the blockchain. e.g., in your Test1 the 49 transactions per second were submitted but only 47 transactions per second were processed hence the 2.4 seconds Max Latency (It is more complex than what I said.)

Q3: Lable 5 represents a peer which is in charge of running and verifying the smart contracts and probably endorsement as well (depending on your endorsement policy) but the label 3 is a world state database peer (more here: https://vitalflux.com/hyperledger-fabric-difference-world-state-db-transaction-logs/ ) and running smart contracts uses more resources.